# SpriteKit and Scrollable List

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I've been trying to figure out an "easy" way to have a scrollable vertical list for my SpriteKit game.

I'm going to use it to implement the shop / upgrades part of my game so I would like the user to be able to scroll down the list to see the different upgrades that are possible.

I've seen quite a few posts on integrating a UIScrollView into SpriteKit but most of them seem to scroll the whole screen.

What I have so far is:

```
-(void) createSceneContents
{
    [super createSceneContents];




    _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,100, 250, 200)];
    _scrollView.contentSize                     = CGSizeMake(2000, 120);
    _scrollView.scrollEnabled                   = YES;
    _scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator  = YES;
    _scrollView.backgroundColor                 = [UIColor brownColor];

    [self.view addSubview:_scrollView];

    //Test sprites for scrolling and zooming
    SKSpriteNode *greenTestSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor]
                                                                 size:CGSizeMake(25, 25)];
    [greenTestSprite setName:@"greenTestSprite"];
    greenTestSprite.position = CGPointMake(25, 125);



    [self addChild:greenTestSprite];

    //[self addChild: [self newMenuNode]];
}
```

I'm trying to think what the easiest way is for me to be able to add the green test sprite into that UIScrollView. can't get my head round the way that other people have done this as they seem to be connecting the scrolling of the UIScrollView with the SKView to make the screen seem like it's scrolling.

I'm sure there is a much easier way of doing this but been searching for a while now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks allot in advance.

Comment: I've put another answer, but you should use [_scrollview addChild:greenTestSprite] if you really want it in the scroll view. You are adding it to the main view currently

Comment: Thanks I presume I can do something to allow clicking on the sprite to be checked.

Comment: @davbryn BTW that doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would avoid using `UIKit` components if possible.  When you have a `UIView` that is parented to `UIKit` components, it makes it difficult to interact with your `SpriteKit` components that live in the `SKView`.  It's pretty easy to subclass `SKNode` and make a "ScrollingNode" that uses gesture recognizers on the `SKView` to do the scrolling.  Here's an example:

https://github.com/JenDobson/SpriteKitScrollingNode

Another great tutorial to take a look at is http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites.  Go to the part at the end on gesture recognizers.

Comment: Hey thanks allot for looking at this. This looks like exactly what I need. I managed to use the UIScrollView but it was problematic and ended just dropping the whole idea and have buttons to scroll instead. I'll try this out tonight!

Comment: Hi Jen, do you know of any way not to have your ScrollingNode not scroll to the full screen. I need it only to scroll within a small section of the screen. Been farthing around and can't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Dave3of5, I've updated my code repository, hopefully you'll find something useful.  Basically I did two things: (1) Use an SKCropNode to mask scrolling content that shouldn't display, and (2) implement the delegate method `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch` for the Scrolling Node to ignore any touches that fall outside the scrolling node's parent.  Check out `JADPartScrollingScene` on the code I posted.  Ideally, you probably want to create a new class called something like `SKScrollingWindow` to encapsulate everything that's going on in the init for that scene.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIKit` in a `SpriteKit` application.

If you use a `UIScrollView` you are going to end up having to get your hands dirty regarding re-use of cells, layout, user-interaction etc. You can actually make a cell look pretty good (and a cell is a `UIView` so you can sack a bunch of subviews in there) if you just use (and customise) a `UITableView`

Your hierarchy would be:

Scene:
      TableView